# Pyspark dataframe drop last element in list column

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with an email column, and I want to get two things: domain (gmail, hotmail, ...) and extension (.com, .uk, .net, .org, ...).

I split the email column and got the extension with the last element.
[image: code]

But I can only get the domain (after the @ and before the extension).
I tried to delete the last element for all list in "test" column without any succes.

- lists in the test column have a variable size*
- domain can contains points (.)

[image: dataframe]

The final dataframe needs to be like:
[image]

Does anyone have a solution?

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove last element from array column of spark you can try below code where I have used array except

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
testdf=spark.createDataFrame([("abc@gmail.com",),("faden@domain.domain2.com",),("fba@a.org",)],"id string")
testdf.withColumn("bef@",F.split("id","@")[0]).withColumn("aft@",F.split("id","@")[1]).withColumn("extention",F.element_at(F.split("aft@",'\.'),-1)).withColumn("domain",F.array_except(F.split("aft@",'\.'),F.array(F.element_at(F.split("aft@",'\.'),-1)))).show()

#output
+--------------------+-----+------------------+---------+-----------------+
|                  id| bef@|              aft@|extention|           domain|
+--------------------+-----+------------------+---------+-----------------+
|       abc@gmail.com|  abc|         gmail.com|      com|          [gmail]|
|faden@domain.doma...|faden|domain.domain2.com|      com|[domain, domain2]|
|           fba@a.org|  fba|             a.org|      org|              [a]|
+--------------------+-----+------------------+---------+-----------------+
```

As per the update if you just want to extract string after last . (which you named as an extension) and string between @ and last . (which you named as domain) then you can use regexp extract as below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
testdf=spark.createDataFrame([("abc@gmail.com",),("faden@domain.domain2.com",),("fba@a.org",),("faden@domain.domain2.dom3.com",)],"id string")
testdf.withColumn("domain",F.regexp_extract("id","(?<=@).+(?=\.)",0)).withColumn("extention",F.regexp_extract("id","[^\.]+$",0)).show()


#output
+--------------------+-------------------+---------+
|                  id|             domain|extention|
+--------------------+-------------------+---------+
|       abc@gmail.com|              gmail|      com|
|faden@domain.doma...|     domain.domain2|      com|
|           fba@a.org|                  a|      org|
|faden@domain.doma...|domain.domain2.dom3|      com|
+--------------------+-------------------+---------+
```